# Rich Text Editor in Django Admin with image upload

Tags: django, django-admin, rich-text-editor

I'm looking for a good Rich Text Editor for the Django Admin Panel.
I need an integrated with Django server which uploads the images. I also
need a functionality of different configurations for two instances of
RichText placed at one admin page.

I've already tried four editors: TinyMce, CKEditor, NiceEdit, and Dojo, but
each of them had some problems with the functionality.

Comment: Can you please describe what you didn't like about/what problems you experienced with the four editors you tried?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience the best thing you could do is to use a markup language like Markdown in your administrative interface and not a RTE, coupled with a javascript editor like [Markitup!](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/),   [django-markitup](https://bitbucket.org/carljm/django-markitup/src) and [django-adminfiles](https://bitbucket.org/carljm/django-adminfiles/src) you get pretty good functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I Think CKEditor Solve Your Problem. You Can Upload Image Too. If You Don't Know How Can Use It In Admin Panel, Comment On This Post Then I Can Help You :-)

Comment: please tell me is there any way around to achieve this with QuillJS?